# How to detect right mouse button release event in javascript?

Tags: javascript, mouseevent

I am using `mouseup` event at the moment but it doesn't work for me.

I use `mousedown` event for left press and `contextmenu` event for right press.

Here is my code:

```
window.addEventListener('mouseup', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  speedDown();
}, true);
```

`speedDown()` is a function for my sprite to slow down its speed. Left press and right press should boost the speed of my sprite in the same way. When I release the button my sprite will slow down. But using the above code when I release my left mouse button it speeds down but it doesn't speed down when I release the right button after pressing it for a few seconds, so I have to press the left button and release it in order to trigger the `mouseup` event.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is this a typo? `('mouseup', e => `

Comment: @Huangism: No, that's ES2015 (aka "ES6"). It's an arrow function.

Comment: Sorry, can you clarify what the events are supposed to do? It's not clear at all what events are meant to speed up the sprite vs. slow it down...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you need a combination of disabling the `contextmenu` (if you can, some browsers don't allow it) and `mouseup`. Also, it's useful to make whatever the user is clicking not user-selectable ([more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/how-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting-using-css)) so that repeated clicks don't select text.

This works for me on Chrome, see comments:

```js
// Avoid the context menu popup
window.addEventListener("contextmenu", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
}, false);

// Listen for mouseup
window.addEventListener("mouseup", function(e) {
  switch (e.button) {
    case 0: // Primary button ("left")
      speedUp();
      break;
    case 2: // Secondary button ("right")
      speedDown();
      break;
  }
}, false);

// Current speed
var speed = 0;
showSpeed();

// Speed functions
function speedUp() {
  ++speed;
  showSpeed();
}

function speedDown() {
  --speed;
  showSpeed();
}

function showSpeed() {
  document.getElementById("speed").innerHTML = speed;
}
```

```css
/* From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/how-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting-using-css */
body {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none; /* iOS Safari */
    -webkit-user-select: none; /* Chrome/Safari/Opera */
     -khtml-user-select: none; /* Konqueror */
       -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
        -ms-user-select: none; /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
            user-select: none; /* Non-prefixed version, currently
                                  not supported by any browser */
}
```

```html
<div>Current speed: <span id="speed">0</span>
</div>
<div>Left-click to speed up</div>
<div>Right-click to slow down</div>
```

Here's a simpler example just demonstrating detecting when mouse buttons are pressed and released:

```js
// Avoid the context menu popup
window.addEventListener("contextmenu", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
}, false);

// Listen for mousedown
window.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e) {
  handle(e, true);
}, false);

// Listen for mouseup
window.addEventListener("mouseup", function(e) {
  handle(e, false);
}, false);

// Our main handler
function handle(e, down) {
  var id;
  switch (e.button) {
    case 0: // Primary button ("left")
      id = "primary-status";
      break;
    case 2: // Secondary button ("right")
      id = "secondary-status";
      break;
  }
  if (id) {
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = down ? "Down" : "Up";
  }
}
```

```css
/* From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/how-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting-using-css */
body {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none; /* iOS Safari */
    -webkit-user-select: none; /* Chrome/Safari/Opera */
     -khtml-user-select: none; /* Konqueror */
       -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
        -ms-user-select: none; /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
            user-select: none; /* Non-prefixed version, currently
                                  not supported by any browser */
}
```

```html
<div>
  Primary ("left") mouse button:
  <span id="primary-status">Unknown</span>
</div>
<div>
  Secondary ("right") mouse button:
  <span id="secondary-status">Unknown</span>
</div>
```

---

**Side note**: Many users configure their mice so that holding *both* buttons down simulates the middle button (`e.button == 1`). You may need to handle that...

Comment: Oh I never even thought about the event on mouseup, good one. I think OP just wants to speed down on left or right release, but your answer answers that anyway

Comment: @Huangism: Hmmm, re-reading the question, you may well be right, I can't tell. :-)

Comment: I want to speedUp when click and speedDown when release the left or right button.

Comment: @newguy: "click" means "press and release." Do you mean you want to speed up on `mousedown` and slow down on `mouseup`? Repeatedly, or just once?

Comment: Sorry I haven't described accurately. I mean press the button. I can handle the press very well. And I can also handle the left button release very well. But I can't make the right button release event work correctly.

Comment: @newguy: Okay. The above shows how to handle releasing the right mouse button. You have to disable `contextmenu`, and then you can handle it in `mouseup`.

Comment: If I disable the `contextmenu` event how can I do a normal speedUp with pressing the right mouse button?

Comment: @newguy: Using `mousedown`. I've added a second example.